# Fragment replaced by first one on orientation change

Tags: android, fragment

I have a problem with one thing - when I change orientation my second fragment, which is active at the moment, replaces by first fragment. I have never so such a behaviour, how can If fix it?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements onDialogClickListener, ITaskLoaderListener {

FragmentManager fm;
public ActionBar actionBar;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pager_layout);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new FirstActivity.FirstFragment(), "loan").commit();

    }
}
```

FirstFragment:

```
public class FirstActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "here");
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        FirstFragment first = new FirstFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, first).commit();
    }
}

public static class FirstFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LoanFragment";

    private View rootView;
    private Button bExtend;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (session.hasLoan()) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_loan, container, false);
            bExtend = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, new SecondActivity.SecondFragment(), "second").addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        }
```

Second Fragment:

```
public class SecondActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        SecondFragment second = new secondFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, second).commit();
    }
}

public static class SecondFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_extend, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

That`s to say when I am in second fragment and try to change orientation then my second fragment will replaced on first fragment. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

`onCreate` will be called on orientation change and you add the first fragment there. You can save which fragment you want to show in `onSaveInstanceState` and then use the instance state in `onCreate` to add the correct fragment.

**EDIT:**

You need to maintain a variable `currentFragmentIndex` and save it in `onSaveInstanceState` like so:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putInt("currentFragment", currentFragment);
}
```

Then retrieve it in `onCreate` and initialize the fragment accordingly:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle!= null){
        currentFragmentIndex= bundle.getInt("currentFragment");
    } else {
        currentFragmentIndex = 0;
    }
    switch(currentFragmentIndex) {
        case 0: 
            // TODO: Add first fragment
            break;
        case 1: 
            // TODO: Add second fragment
            break;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change `currentFragmentIndex` to `1` when you switch to the second fragment.

Comment: Sorry, could take me a small example of hot to save current fragment in onSaveInstanceState. It`s neccessary to save only fragment tag in the bundle or it`s possible to do somehow better? And as I understand i Should do this trick in onCreate of first fragment, not seocnd, is it so?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, though as a note, I'm using the v4 support library. After reading Sapan Diwakar's answer, I wondered if this was necessary; instead, I tried this...

```
if (null == mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_HERE)) {
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()./*blah blah blah*/.commit();
}
```

...so the original fragment is only instantiated/attached if there's nothing already attached where it's supposed to go.

I've tested this a bit and it seems to be fine... of course, the fact that it *works* doesn't mean it's a *good idea*, but I'm too new at this to know why it wouldn't be. If anyone can chime in on that, it'd be useful.

Thanks for posting this question, and also to everyone with input!